# Memory Bug in MRProgress

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mobile, memory-management

Searched for hours trying to figure this out. Most people say use NSZombies but the tutorials out there are not for Xcode 6 which seems to have changed "Instruments" a lot.

I'm using the MRProgress library. The progress overlay view comes up fine, and dismisses fine, then maybe 10 seconds after its dismissal the app crashes with `exc_bad_access code=1 address=0x2000000c` at the line in the `MRProgressOverlayView.m` file at the line:

```
self.blurView.maskView = self.blurMaskView;
```

Which is just under:

```
self.blurMaskView.frame = self.dialogView.bounds;
```

I've tried to wrap these two lines in an if statement like so:

```
if (self.blurView) {
    self.blurMaskView.frame = self.dialogView.bounds;
    self.blurView.maskView = self.blurMaskView;
}
```

Which didn't solve the bug, so I then tried to go crazy with it like so:

```
if (self.dialogView) {
    if (self.blurMaskView) {
        if (self.blurView) {
            self.blurMaskView.frame = self.dialogView.bounds;
            self.blurView.maskView = self.blurMaskView;
        }
    }
}
```

Which, unsurprisingly, also didn't solve the bug. Here's how I call the overlay view:

```
Viewcontroller.h

@property (nonatomic, strong) MRProgressOverlayView *hud;

Viewcontroller.m

self.hud = [MRProgressOverlayView showOverlayAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
self.hud.mode = MRProgressOverlayViewModeIndeterminate;
self.hud.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.267 green:0.467 blue:0.741 alpha:1];
self.hud.titleLabelText = @"Uploading...";
self.hud.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:16.0f];
```

Here's how I dismiss it:

```
[MRProgressOverlayView dismissOverlayForView:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
```

It doesn't seem like anyone else using this library is having the issue, so it's hard to find an answer. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: I turned Zombies on, and now I get this error

```
[10741:2617639] *** -[_UIReplicantContentView _maskView]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x15cb2550
```

Comment: Have you turned Enabled the Memory Management items: Scribble, Guard Edges, Gard Malloc and Zombie Objects in the target Scheme?

Comment: @Zaph I wouldn't know what to do after enabling those. I searched for tutorials, most said to run Xcode with 'Instructions' and look for the messages but the UI of Instructions has changed. What am I supposed to do after enabling these things?

Comment: Two basic paths of action: 1. Spend the time to learn about memory, and how to use the development tools. 2. Give up on writing code. Tutorials are not the only path and tend to provide only limited superficial information. There is substantial documentation of the development tools , memory and all the other topics having to do with writing code. In this case take a week to study these things, that will serve you well in the future.

Comment: @Zaph O...kay. Don't see how that's useful toward this question but enjoy your pretentious pie. I'm actually searching for an answer.

Comment: Did you get any other information?

Comment: There is an open issue for this over at Github: https://github.com/mrackwitz/MRProgress/issues/75